# How come this Prolog rule doesn't go into a infinity loop?

Tags: prolog

I have following facts and rules:

```
one(s).
one(t).
two(X,Y) :- one(X), one(Y), three(X), \+three(Y), \+two(Y,X).
three(s).
```

For the query `two(Y,X).` I get this result:

```
?- two(Y,X).
Y = s,
X = t ;
false.
```

I don't understand why the results are `Y=s` and `X=t`. Why does Prolog don't go infinitely many times into `\+two(Y,X)`? Does Prolog remember which predicates have already been processed?

Comment: There is only one way for `one(X), one(Y), three(X)` to succeed, which is `X = s` and `Y = t`. Then  `\+ three(Y)` succeeds since `three(t)` fails, and `\+ two(Y,X)` succeeds because `two(t,s)` fails. In short, `two(Y,X)` has only one solution, which is the one your query shows. Prolog doesn't call `\+ two(Y,X)` infinitely many times because there aren't infinitely many choices for a possible solution.

Comment: Exactly what @lurker says. Note that something like `two(X, Y) :- \+ two(Y, X), ...` would produce an infinite loop. But because you have constrained what `X` and `Y` can be prior to the recursion, it won’t.

Comment: You can use `trace.` to see how Prolog obtains a certain result.

Comment: I think I got it now. Thanks for the help @ all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This succeeds because Prolog uses *negation as finite failure*.

If we evaluate the Prolog predicate, we see that:

```
[trace]  ?- two(X, Y).
   Call: (8) two(_660, _662) ? creep
   Call: (9) one(_660) ? creep
   Exit: (9) one(s) ? creep
   Call: (9) one(_662) ? creep
   Exit: (9) one(s) ? creep
   Call: (9) three(s) ? creep
   Exit: (9) three(s) ? creep
   Call: (9) three(s) ? creep
   Exit: (9) three(s) ? creep
   Redo: (9) one(_662) ? creep
   Exit: (9) one(t) ? creep
   Call: (9) three(s) ? creep
   Exit: (9) three(s) ? creep
   Call: (9) three(t) ? creep
   Fail: (9) three(t) ? creep
   Redo: (8) two(s, t) ? creep
   Call: (9) two(t, s) ? creep
   Call: (10) one(t) ? creep
   Exit: (10) one(t) ? creep
   Call: (10) one(s) ? creep
   Exit: (10) one(s) ? creep
   Call: (10) three(t) ? creep
   Fail: (10) three(t) ? creep
   Fail: (9) two(t, s) ? creep
   Redo: (8) two(s, t) ? creep
   Exit: (8) two(s, t) ? creep
X = s,
Y = t .
```

So in a first "path" that fails `X` and `Y` are both set to `s`:

```
two(X,Y) :-
    one(X),     %% X = s
    one(Y),     %% Y = s
    three(X),   %% X = s
    \+three(Y), %% Y = s, fail
    \+two(Y,X).
```

But then we backtrack over the `one(Y)` call, and we obtain:

```
two(X,Y) :-
    one(X),     %% X = s
    one(Y),     %% Y = t
    three(X),   %% X = s
    \+three(Y), %% Y = t
    \+two(Y,X)  %% call two(t, s).
```

Now `\+ p(X, Y)` is considered `true`, given `p(X, Y)` can not be satisfied, and gets stuck in an infinite loop. We thus call `two(t, s)`, and this fails, since:

```
two(t,s) :-
    one(t),     %% succeeds
    one(s),     %% succeeds
    three(t),   %% fails
    \+three(s), %% 
    \+two(s,t)  %%
```

So `three(t)` fails, and since there are no backtracking opportunities here, `two(t, s)` thus ends. So that means that `two(t, s)` has finite failure, hence `\+ two(t, s)` succeeds, and thus `two(X, Y)` succeeds with `X = s, Y = t`.

Answer (score 1):

You have the following predicates defined:

```
one(s).
one(t).
two(X,Y) :- one(X), one(Y), three(X), \+three(Y), \+two(Y,X).
three(s).
```

The predicate `two(X,Y)` is equivalent to

```
two(X,Y) :- (X=s ; X=t), (Y=s ; Y=t), (X=s), \+(Y=s), \+two(Y,X).
=
two(X,Y) :- (X=s, (Y=s ; Y=t), X=s ; X=t, (Y=s ; Y=t), X=s), \+(Y=s), \+two(Y,X).
=
two(X,Y) :- (X=s, (Y=s ; Y=t), s=s ; X=t, (Y=s ; Y=t), t=s), \+(Y=s), \+two(Y,X).
=
two(X,Y) :- (X=s, (Y=s ; Y=t) ; false), \+(Y=s), \+two(Y,X).
=
two(X,Y) :- ((X=s, Y=s ; false), \+(Y=s) ; (X=s, Y=t ; false), \+(Y=s)), \+two(Y,X).
=
two(X,Y) :- ((X=s, Y=s ; false), \+(s=s) ; (X=s, Y=t ; false), \+(t=s)), \+two(Y,X).
=
two(X,Y) :- (X=s, Y=t ; false), true, \+two(Y,X).
=
two(X,Y) :- (X=s, Y=t, \+two(Y,X) ; false).
=
two(s,t) :- (true, \+two(t,s) ; false).
=
two(s,t) :- (true ; false).
```

and that's what you're getting.